# Custom RSS feeds for my Ghost blog

Tags: mailchimp, ghost-blog

I’m new to web development … just dipping my toes in

Is there a way to get custom RSS feeds with Ghost?

I have a list of my family members on mailchimp and I’d like to send them a weekly summary of what happened on my blog this week.

Rather than firing off a mail every time I post something, I’d like to send them a weekly or fortnightly email.

I don’t know if that is a Ghost question or a Mailchimp question.

I’m running 0.5.8 on CentOS on a Linode at http://mjbraganza.com

Would appreciate any input.

Comment: Why a custom RSS feed? Why not use the default one: http://mjbraganza.com/rss/

Comment: @mikedidthis, because I don’t know how to make a weekly summary out of that one. Is there a way to get Mailchimp to check only weekly and generate summaries? or a way to customise the default rss feed? any pointers would be handy. Thank you

Comment: Seems so: http://blog.mailchimp.com/rss-to-email-tutorial/

Comment: @mikedidthis, And why in God’s good name didn’t I find it when I looked?! This is exactly what I want :) Thank you.

Comment: P.S. - how do I go about marking your comment as an answer? I can’t seem to be able to do it!

Comment: Sadly you can't. However I suggest you post my comment as your answer. Get some rep and nice badge :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@mikedidthis helped me out with this one.

Mailchimp already has a way of doing all the heavy lifting.

> Seems so: blog.mailchimp.com/rss-to-email-tutorial –  mikedidthis Feb 6 at 13:22